# Remote access in laravel 5.4

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-5.4

i am new in laravel please guide me about remote access on same network.
i want to share my **Laravel Project** on the other computer which is connected on same network.I tried the following command by **Git Bash** but it works only on my PC not worked on the other PC.
 `/c/xampp/htdocs/myproject (master)
$ php artisan serve --host=192.168.100.5 --port=5000`

Comment: May be your apache config is stopping you from sharing your application via local network. Check the apache config. I think by default it will be taking connections only from `localhost` and loop back address `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Try [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) this is easiest way to share your Laravel project